# Derivative of $(2/3)^{k-1}\cdot k$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

I want to find the derivative of $f(k)$ but [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20(2%2F3)%5E(k-1)*k) tells me that it has a $\log$ in it, I have no idea where this $\log$ comes from, did I use the product rule here the wrong?

$f(k)=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{(k-1)}\cdot k$

$f'(k)=(k-1)\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-2}\cdot k + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-1}$

Comment: You're differentiating $2^k$, not $k^2$. Power rule is not applicable.

Comment: I think @user296602 has hit the nail on the head. +1. Note that there is a useful generalization that encompasses both $x^a$ and $a^x$; if $f$ and $g$ are functions of $x$, and $'$ denotes differentiation with respect to $x$, then $$(f^g)' = gf^{g-1}\cdot f' +f^g\log f\cdot g'$$  If $g$ is constant, you recover the power rule, and if $f$ is constant you recover the exponential rule.

Comment: I don’t quite understand the downvotes. The OP has done everything we request—bring research and explain personal attempts—and I’m sure that plenty of students can learn from this post in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

note that $$(a^x)'=a^x\ln(a)$$ and your first derivative is given by $$\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-1}\left(\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)k+1\right)$$

Comment: this just slept out of my mind, feel bad for asking now ...

Comment: You've answered the title, not the body (there was a discrepancy in the title, and it has been fixed.) Should be $(2/3)^{k-1}\cdot k$.

Comment: ok thank you for the hint, it is just corrected, important such a difference

Answer (score 2):

It should be:
$$f'(k)=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-1}k\ln\frac{2}{3} + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-1}$$
because $(a^k)'_{k}=a^k\ln{a}$.